# Customized relationship between elements on same page

Tags: looker-studio

I have a page with diagrams for sales.
I have a control element where the user selects a vendor is select - filtering all page diagrams to sold items from that vendor.
I want to add a table with detail item lines (pivot grouped by customer, invoice …). In that table I want to see all invoice lines - including lines with items from other vendors. ** Notice: This table should still only show invoices that contain at least one item from the selected vendor.
How do I do that?

Is it possible to connect a second data source with a (customized) relationship to control elements based on the first data source?)